# 32 bit versus 64 bit machine for software development question

Tags: 64-bit, hardware, virtualization

I am pricing a new software development machine and looking at the dell precision series.

When I get to this screen:

http://www.dell.com/content/topics/reftopic.aspx/pub/products/precn_kat?c=us&cs=555&l=en&s=biz&~section=T7400

The first choice is: Buy a Precision WorkStation T7400 32bit Now!
and the second choice is: Buy a Precision WorkStation T7400 64bit Now!

am I really at that point just deciding which software I want installed? or is there actually a different chipset depending on the choice.

I don't want to limit my options down the road by picking the wrong one - I can always upgrade the software - but I don't want to have to replace hardware.

BTW: This will be for SD of a Microsoft stack, asp.net, vs 2008, sql server etc and I would like to start using virtualization (probably from MS) with this machine purchase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64-Bit, but just not XP64 (Which Dell offers as a downgrade). Driver situation is quite awful, and there are some [incompatibilities in Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_Professional_x64_Edition#Known_issues). If you need/want to stick to XP, go 32-Bit, if you want to use Vista or Windows Server 2008, 64-Bit is fine.

The only difference is the operating system anyway, so you can freely switch between installing 32 or 64 Bit Windows, you may just need to buy another License.

Comment: Hmmm... I run 64bit XP on a Dell T5400 Precision for VisualStudio (&Direct3D) development.  Only annoying driver problem was for one of our networked printers.  Would hate to run 32bit XP (and waste of the 8GByte RAM in the box!).

Answer (score 6):

Both options give you the same choice of processors, they are all 64-bit capable. It's just a matter of whether a 32-bit or 64-bit version of the OS is preinstalled on it.

I would go with the 64-bit option simply because, in my experience, you can easily run both 32-bit and 64-bit VMs on a 64-bit platform, but are limited to 32-bit VMs on a 32-bit platform.

Answer (score 4):

100% 64bit. RAM is cheap and you'll eventually want to use more than 4GB of it, especially if you've going to be running virtual machines.

Comment: Yes, but if I pick a 32 bit machine, is the hardware different? or just the software? It makes a difference when you shop the outlet store, some are listed as 32bit some as 64bit, but I not sure if thats just the software thats different that I can upgrade, or hardware that I can't??

Comment: It is just the software. I don't think either Intel or AMD make 32-bit only processors any more.

Comment: I believe 3GB is the cap on Win32, not 4GB.  I happen to have a Win32 machine at work with 1GB that's never been used :)

Answer (score 3):

64bit all the way. Vista64 is mature at this point, I haven't run into any issues.  If you need 32bit for any older peripherals you might have, install XP32 as a VM.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't really buy a 32-bit PC nowadays. I think the OS is the only different between the 32bit and 64bit version.

For .NET development it doesn't matter whether you're using a 64-bit OS or not. However 64-bit SQL Server maybe running faster.

And you'll also need more than 4GB RAM (especially if you run virtual machines), so I don't really see any reason to choose a 32-bit OS over a 64-bit one.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for 64bit with 64bit Operating System. Only problem i encountered so far is that 32bit apps cannot access 64-dlls -> For example the context menu of TotalCommander won't show 64bit apps (e.g subversion) which might be inconvenient for development.

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to get 64bit drivers for exotic or very new hardware, so if that's a concern for you, you might want to stick to the 32bit OS.